# How to select a tmux session in detached mode for commands like split-pane?

Tags: tmux

I want to write a startup script that launches multiple tmux sessions in detached mode.
Minimal example:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmux new-session -d -s "session-a" -n "window-a1"
tmux new-session -d -s "session-b" -n "window-b1"

# Splits session-b pane 0 vertically
tmux split-pane -v
```

Now I want to apply some commands, e.g. `split-pane`, `send-keys` etc. to a pane in `session-a` without attaching to it.
I imagine something like this:

```
tmux select-pane -s session-a -t 0
tmux split-pane -h
```

but there is no `-s` argument and I can't find any `select-session` command.

Note: Reordering commands is a workaround but I'm specifically looking for a solution to select the pane of a particular session specified by name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-t` option to specify session and window.

```bsh
tmux split-pane -h -t [$SESSION_NAME:]$WINDOW_ID
```